# Why script working only in footer wordpress enqueue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with load jquery in header. When I load jquery script in footer everything working fine. Both in the footer and in the header, the script loads correctly, but its functions only work in the footer

```
function script_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('some-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', [], '2.0', false);


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because methods and statements in JavaScript files do't work until after the elements (DOM tree) you are working on has been loaded
Unlike style files that work at any time (css)

Comment: So what I should do, when I want load this script in header?

Comment: An extension that function the file wait for the elements to load, namely: <body onload="functionAllJS();"> or document.onload = function () {//HERE_CODE_JS} or window.onload = function(){//HERE_CODE_JS}

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue any script that has a dependency to jQuery after jQuery is enqueue and specify the dependency.

in practical you want something looking like this

```
<?php 
/**
* Theme scripts
*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery js
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    */
    $test_jquery_js = @fopen( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'r' );
    if ( $test_jquery_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array() );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );

    /**
    * Register then enqueue session js
    */
    wp_register_script( 'app_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array( 'jquery_js' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'app_js' );
  };
}; ?>
```

Here we register and enqueue jQuery first THEN when we enqueue our `app.js` file. We specify the dependency to jQuery via the `array( 'jquery_js' )` where `'jquery_js'` is the handle we set when we enqueued jQuery.